# How to create output dataframe name as per the input dataframe name in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, automation, lm

I was trying to do regression modeling on multiple dataframes.

My expected outcome would name as per the input dataframe name, so I wonder how can I achieve that!

Till now what I did,

```
list.dfs <- list(BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86228,BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86235,BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86256,
                 BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86257,BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86267,BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86269)


for (i in 1:length(list.dfs)){

 lm.res <- lm(
    as.formula(paste(colnames(list.dfs[[i]])[1], "~ .")),
    data=list.dfs[[i]]
  )

  assign(paste0("lm_Res",i), lm.res, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

This delivered the output dataframe as,

```
lm_Res1
lm_Res2
lm_Res3
lm_Res4
lm_Res5
lm_Res6
```

My expected output dataframe name should be,

```
lm_Res_BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86228
lm_Res_BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86235
lm_Res_BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86256
lm_Res_BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86257
lm_Res_BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86267
lm_Res_BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86269
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create `list.dfs` with named arguments, therefore, use

```
list.dfs <- list(BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86228 = BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86228, ...)
```

or more convenient, use the `lst()` function from the `tibble` library:

```
list.dfs <- tibble::lst(BrC15sy_h16_d_EE86228, ...)
```

Finally, replace `paste0("lm_Res",i)` inside the `assign` call with

```
paste0("lm_Res_", names(list.dfs)[i])
```